# After adding server to domain, logging on via RDP is 20 times slower

Tags: domain, remote-desktop

I'm not sure what is going on but I have been building out a new environment remotely.  All the VMs I spin up that start out as 2019 servers in a WORKGROUP seems to respond to RDP requests extremely fast and I see no delay at all.  The few servers out of the bunch that I have added to a new domain recently created seem to have a delay that is at least 20 times slower in response to my initial RDP requests before I see the login credentials request.

Any idea why the domain is slowing things down?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you could start by checking your DNS settings of the servers. I'm assuming you have one or more Domain Controllers (DC's). When you login to one of your servers, a request is made to that DC to ultimately check your credentials. However, when this connection is slow or the DNS name is resolving slowly, or not (thus falling back), it may take a while because of the timeout.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be a "slow" connection though.  DNS is solid, fast and setup perfectly from what I can tell.